# How does the async retry behaviour of Lambda works when integrated with AWS Step Functions?

Tags: asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, retry-logic

I have noticed that we can configure the retry behaviour on the Lambda function as well as in your state machine and wanted to know which of these would take precedence/how they would interact.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda retry configuration only applies to asynchronous invocations, whereas by default **Step Functions invokes Lambda synchronously**. Lambda does not retry synchronous invokes, so in this case the responsibility of retrying any failed requests would fall on Step Functions and whatever retry configuration you had defined.

Step Functions does have the option to invoke Lambda functions asynchronously by adding the parameter "InvocationType": "Event" to the lambda:invoke task. When using this parameter, Step Functions will submit an event to Lambda's internal queue which Lambda will poll and process. In this scenario, any failure during the invocation itself would be retried or sent to your DLQ by Lambda per your Event Invoke Configuration. The only situation with this invocation mode where Step Functions would retry the request would be if it failed to submit the event into the queue in the first place. This could happen if you had a malformed payload for example (although a retry wouldn't help in this case) or on rare occasion due to a service exception.